# TypeError: elem.autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I am new to Angular.JS. I am struggling last 6 hours.

I read the data from HTTP and send back to the view as a autocomplete state. Previously it was a select box. I decided to change to autocomplete from a select box.

Plunker Link: http://embed.plnkr.co/MbhALuekWNDqnYFyjbOF/

Here have to return two values. One is ID and another one is the description. Because user going search by description. but have to return back ID of the respective user selection.

**Error:**

```
angular.min.js:124 TypeError: elem.autocomplete is not a function
at Object.link (main.js:217)
at angular.min.js:17
at wa (angular.min.js:85)
at q (angular.min.js:71)
at f (angular.min.js:62)
at q (angular.min.js:71)
at f (angular.min.js:62)
at f (angular.min.js:62)
at f (angular.min.js:62)
at f (angular.min.js:62) "<input client-complete="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="vm.client.COMPANY_DESC" placeholder="enter name" type="text">"
```

```js
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTable', 'ngResource']);

  app.directive('clientComplete',['$filter',clientCompleteDir]);

  app.controller('AccountMappingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'NgTableParams', AccountMappingcontroller]);

  function AccountMappingcontroller($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var vm = this;
    vm.client ={COMPANY_ID:'', COMPANY_DESC:''};
   
      /* $http.get("http://localhost:52087/api/companydetails").then(function(response) {
      var convertToJson = angular.fromJson(response.data);
      $scope.dataSource = convertToJson;
    }); */
    
   $scope.dataSource = [{'COMPANY_ID':'10001','COMPANY_DESC':'THIRDROCK','COMPANY_CURRENCY':'AUS','ACTIVE':true,'IS_HEADOFFICE':true,'ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_ID':'1'},{'COMPANY_ID':'10002','COMPANY_DESC':'OBN TECH','COMPANY_CURRENCY':'INR','ACTIVE':true,'IS_HEADOFFICE':true,'ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_ID':'1'}];
  
    $scope.setClientData = function(item){
      if (item){
        vm.client = item;
      }
    }

  } //controller

  //directive
  function clientCompleteDir($filter) {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
              elem.autocomplete({
                  source: function (request, response) {

                      //term has the data typed by the user
                      var params = request.term;

                      //simulates api call with odata $filter
                      var data = scope.dataSource;
                      if (data) {
                          var result = $filter('filter')(data, {COMPANY_DESC:params});
                          angular.forEach(result, function (item) {
                              item['value'] = item['COMPANY_DESC'];
                          });
                      }
                      response(result);

                  },
                  minLength: 1,
                  select: function (event, ui) {
                     //force a digest cycle to update the views
                     scope.$apply(function(){
                      scope.setClientData(ui.item);
                     });
                  },

              });
          }

      };
    }

})(angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Account Mapping Maintenance </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="./vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link href="./vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
  <link href="./build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@4.0.0/bundles/ng-table.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="nav-md" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AccountMappingCtrl as vm">

  <input client-complete class="form-control" ng-model="vm.client.COMPANY_DESC" placeholder="enter name" type="text">
  <input client-complete class="form-control" ng-model="vm.client.COMPANY_ID" placeholder="enter name" type="hidden">
  
    <!-- Angular CDN -->
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@4.0.0/bundles/ng-table.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="./vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="./vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="./vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="./build/js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Controller/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to load jquery, than jquery-ui and than angular to eliminate that error:

```
 <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="jquery-ui@1.11.2" data-semver="1.11.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script data-require="jquery-ui@1.11.2" data-semver="1.11.2" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
```

Here is small working plunker with one input for filtering source data, hoppefuly it will make easier for you to continue: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tTflQ5EDuNqtecvYmCdF?p=preview)

(start typing THIRDROCK)